# Android Sqlite IN, NOT IN syntax

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to run `NOT IN` select where `NOT IN` list is dynamic. Something like

```
SELECT id, type FROM CONTACTS where type NOT IN ('connect','answer')
```

In the code my futile attempts were:

```
db.query(TABLE, new String[] { "id", ""}, " type NOT IN (?)", "connect,answer", 
    null, null, null); // didn't work
db.query(TABLE, new String[] { "id", ""}, " type NOT IN (?)", "'connect','answer'", 
null, null, null); // didn't work
```

My take on this is that `?` substitution treats my comma list as single argument. I did find a solution but it is rather ugly so I won't post it here until someone comes forward with something more elegant

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot place just one '?' instead of a list of values. As such, there is little to gain from trying to parametrize lists. One can, of course, create 2,4,16-value prepared statements `..." type NOT IN (?,?)", new String[]{ "connect","answer" },...` but even on a server with remote RDBMS it has questionable value.
Instead, do

```
db.query(TABLE, new String[] { "id", ""}, " type NOT IN ('connect','answer')", 
     null, null, null, null);
```

if the list is dynamic, you will have to escape the strings and put them into single quoted list.

Comment: If the strings in question are from a list you provide rather than a list the user provides, then you can know that they're safe and don't even have to escape them (unless they contain a ').

Comment: That is pretty much the solution I ended up with. Was hoping for a little trick but I'm guessing there are none. Still want to wait a bit to see if there will be any alternative suggestions

Comment: More familiar with Hibernate Criteria whose IN is well supported, however not found any equivalent in Android SDK.

Answer (score 3):

You can use String.format to dynamic set the args.

for example:

```
db.query(TABLE, new String[] { "id", ""}, " type NOT IN (?)", "connect,answer", null, null, null);
```

=>

```
String argsArrayToString(List<String> args) {
    StringBuilder argsBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    argsBuilder.append("(");
    final int argsCount = args.size();
    for (int i=0; i<argsCount; i++) {
        argsBuilder.append(args.get(i));
        if (i < argsCount - 1) {
            argsBuilder.append(",");
        }
    }
    argsBuilder.append(")");
}

db.query(TABLE, new String[] { "id", ""}, String.format(" type NOT IN (%s)", argsArrayToString(arrays)), null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: don't add "( " and ")" while converting list to string

Answer (score 1):

You can have it dynamically use "not in" if you dynamically create a String that contains the list of "not in" values and then append them to the end of your sql string like in the following:

```
public static Vector selectAllFormTypesForAccountIgnoringFormVersions(
        int accountId, String formsIgnored) {
protected final static String selectAllFormTypesForAccountIgnoringFormVersions = "SELECT DISTINCT FormType.*"
        + " FROM FormType, Form WHERE Form.accountId=? AND FormType.formTypeContentId = Form.formTypeContentId"
        + " AND Form.formVersionId NOT IN (";

    Vector allFormTypes = new Vector();
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = { Integer.toString(accountId)};

    try {
        DataManager_Platform dataManager = (DataManager_Platform) DataManager_Platform
                .getDataManager();
        db = (SQLiteDatabase) dataManager.getDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(
                selectAllFormTypesForAccountIgnoringFormVersions + formsIgnored + ")",
                selectionArgs);

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                FormType_Platform formType = new FormType_Platform();
                formType.populateModel(cursor);
                allFormTypes.add(formType);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (db != null) {
                db.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return allFormTypes;
}
```