# How to add where clause while querying for mms-sms conversation?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-query

I need a conversation cursor which does not have given addresses.
This is how i am getting the cursor :

```
final Uri inboxURI = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations/");    
final String[] projection = new String[] { Sms._ID, Sms.THREAD_ID, Sms.ADDRESS, Sms.BODY, Sms.DATE, Sms.READ};    
Cursor cursor = cr.query(inboxURI, projection, Sms.ADDRESS+" NOT IN (?)", new String[]{"456454"}, Telephony.Sms.Inbox.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
```

This gives me an empty cursor. However this works fine if null is given as selection and selection_args.

Is this correct way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain why you're doing this : Sms.ADDRESS+" NOT IN (?)"

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707367/android-sqlite-in-not-in-syntax